# How to reference the file I just created powershell?

Tags: file, powershell, csv

I want to create a file in powershell using a timestamp for name and then pass that to my next step which would add content to it. Is there another way of doing this other than searching for latest file in the folder?

Comment: Please post code.

Comment: There are many methods. Also, no need to create an empty file to add something.

Comment: `New-Item` normally write created item to pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

As [@PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830511/how-to-reference-the-file-i-just-created-powershell#comment76641551_44830511) mentioned in the comments: `New-Item` outputs the created item, so you can simply capture that in a variable:

```
$newFile = New-Item ...
```